# Convert a List containing List<double> to single flatten array

Tags: c#, arrays, list

to convert a list to array[,] there is code:

```
double[,] arr = new double[list.Count, list[0].Length];
for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < list[0].Length; j++)
    {
        arr[i, j] = list[i][j];
    }
}
```

I want to convert it to flatten array so Using the fact

```
Flattened array index computation

array[(Y coordinate * width) + X coordinate]

2D array index computation

array[Y coordinate, X coordinate]
```

code changes to

```
double[] arr = new double[list.Count * list[0].Length];
for (int i = 0; i < list.Count  ; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < list[0].Length; j++)
    {
           arr[i] = list[i * list[0].Length +  j];
    }

}
```

But What would be the code to convert a `List < List < double > >` to flatten array?
Is it possible to do it in 2 loops as the above code?

the `List<List<double>>` represents a  `double[,] arr`

Comment: Shouldn't `arr[i] = list[i * list[0].Length +  j];` be `arr[i * list[0].Length +  j] = list[i][j];` ?

Comment: If you want to convert a list of lists to a multi-dimensional array, that's not "flattening". Flattening a list of lists would result in a single-dimensional array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a loop (i.e. without LINQ) would be something like

```
public static void Main()
{
    List<List<double>> listOfLists = new List<List<double>>();

    listOfLists.Add(new List<double>() { 1, 2, 3 });
    listOfLists.Add(new List<double>() { 4, 6 });

    int flatLength = 0;
    foreach (List<double> list in listOfLists)
        flatLength += list.Count;

    double[] flattened = new double[flatLength];

    int iFlat = 0;

    foreach (List<double> list in listOfLists)
        foreach (double d in list)
            flattened[iFlat++] = d;

    foreach (double d in flattened)
        Console.Write("{0} ", d);

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Honestly I'm not 100% sure what you're asking, but to flatten a `List<List<>>` you can use `SelectMany` from Linq, here's a simple example:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var first = new List<double> {1, 2, 3};
        var second = new List<double> { 3, 4, 5 };

        var lists = new List<List<double>> {first, second};

        var flatten = lists.SelectMany(a => a).ToArray();

        foreach (var i in flatten)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(i);
        }
    }
```

Comment: How would that query be in for loop?

Answer (score 2):

Given the fact that your list ist a nested enumerable you can simply use Linq.

```
double[] array = nestedList.SelectMany(a => a).ToArray();
```